# A minimal Nightwatch test doesn't work with Firefox 57

Tags: nightwatch.js, webdriver-manager

Here is a reproduction repo:
https://github.com/anatoliyarkhipov/nightwatch-firefox

It's a clear installation of `nightwatch` and `webdriver-manager`. The test opens http://example.com, clicks on the link and checks some content on the next page.

The problem is that if I run it in Firefox, it fails on the first step where we check that `<body>` is visible. If we change `firefox` to `chrome` in `nightwatch.conf.js`, then the test will pass.

I run it on Windows 10, Firefox 57.0 (64-bit).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing path to the driver files in your config files

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Plus7! I configured path to the `geckodriver` - https://github.com/anatoliyarkhipov/nightwatch-firefox/commit/fcd3f91b4563e67f50eba612473167e8f86573f8 - but it still seems to not be working. Could you please add a more details on how to properly configure the `geckodriver`?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/IvanNaumenko/test-project-nightwatch-cucumber

Hey!

This is nightwatch with cucumber. Download and write tests like in example here. You won't regret

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right version of geckodriver. Get the latest here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases